# Erro em biblioteca ao executar fora da IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, dll, biblioteca

Eu estou conectando a aplicação à um dispositivo bluetooth através de uma biblioteca, roda perfeitamente dentro do NetBeans, mas depois quando vou rodar pelo .jar dá esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: an_in
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at plux.newdriver.bioplux.Device.<clinit>(Device.java:9)
        at biosignalsplugin.Methods.FindDevice(Methods.java:51)
        at biosignalsplugin.BioSignalsPlugin.main(BioSignalsPlugin.java:31)
```

Veio junto com a biblioteca um arquivo DLL que já coloquei na pasta system32, a biblioteca eu importei usando o Add Jar/folder e está perfeito na IDE, não faço ideia do que acontece quando eu rodo o .jar

Comment: Cara sem ser chato nem nada, mas vc deu uma lida na documentação? Assim como a pergunta anterior eu achei a solução pra você lendo lá, a resposta desse problema pode estar nela.

Comment: Eu entendo a desconfiança kkk, mas acabei tendo que ler toda a documentação para criar a aplicação, e lá não tinha nada sobre a build, só sobre a as duas classes que tem no projeto e as exceptions ("não tem essa exception lá... pq nem encontrando a biblioteca está").

Comment: E sem saber que biblioteca você está utilizando, fica ainda mais difícil de te ajudar. Por favor adicione as informações das bibliotecas utilizadas.